# Prove we can't Finding an element $A[i]=i^2$ in sorted array with $\log n$ time.

Tags: algorithms, searching

> We are given a sorted array$A[1..n]$, we are searching to find an
> element that  $A[i]=i^2$ in array. How we can prove that we can't do it in
> $O(\log n)$?

My idea:
do a linear search in array in $O(n)$, and check: if
$A[i]=i^2$ print it.
The teacher say it can't be done in $O(\log n)$,and i want to prove it can't be done in $O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: This might be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com – but make sure to read their FAQ first!

Comment: I am tempted to say that $A[i]=i^2=-1$ is a constant array.

Comment: Consider for example $[0, 3, 8, ..., n^2-1]$ which doesn’t sattisfy the property because each entry is $n^2-1$. Now suppose you set an entry $i$ to be $i^2$. Clearly, the array is still ordered but it does now satisfy the property. To distinguish both cases you have to inspect the position $i$ but since this position has been chosen arbitrarily, that means you have to inspect all the positions, which requires linear time.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136620/755